# Extract substring between two colons / special characters

Tags: r, regex

I want to extract "SUBSTRING" with sub() from the following string:

```
attribute <- "S4Q7b1_t1_r1: SUBSTRING: some explanation: some explanation - ..."
```

I used the following code, but unfortunately it didn't work:

```
sub(".*: (.*) : .*", "\\1", attribute)
```

Does anyone know an answer for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sub("^[^:]*: ([^:]*).*", "\\1", attribute)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4oCeQM/1)

You need to rely on negated character classes, `[^:]` that matches any char but `:`, since `.*` matches *greedily* any 0 or more chars. Also, your pattern contains a space before `:` and it is missing in the string.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^:]*` - any 0+ chars other than `:`
- `:`  - a colon with a space
  -`([^:]*)` - Capturing group 1 (`\1` refers to this value): any 0+ chars other than `:`
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

[R Demo](https://ideone.com/8WNjqV):

```
attribute <- "S4Q7b1_t1_r1: SUBSTRING: some explanation: some explanation - ..."
sub("^[^:]*: ([^:]*).*", "\\1", attribute) 
## => [1] "SUBSTRING"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that it was possible now. I will keep that in mind and thanks again!